# SQL Server window functions: can you do a ROW BETWEEN type construct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

This is my version of SQL Server:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4064.0 (X64)   Feb 25 2011 13:56:11   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)

I want to do something like this (which works in Sybase):

```
SELECT AVG(ct) OVER (PARTITION BY val1 
                         ORDER BY val2 ASC ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM table
```

Is there a way to implement something like this WITHOUT some nasty self join, or a subquery that uses row number etc? I suppose if I HAVE to do that I will, but I'd love to use the best most compact code.

EDIT:
Per the comments, here is what I'd like to do.

I have a `time_id` and a value. I want to take a moving average (1 week) of the value. Pretty simple.

Comment: Your table structure and sample data/expected output would be very helpful here

Comment: I think there's no syntax like that in SQL Server, but if you would explain us how that works, we might come up with a (however ugly) subsitution for it.

Comment: In any event, from my approximate understanding of this query, it seems very likely that you'll have to do what you are so reluctant to do, i.e. use a (nasty?) self-join as well as ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: FWIW [this syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx) is in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this that will perform well in SQL Server. I would strongly suggest to do this in the application. It will probably outperform anything you can do in T-SQL by an order of magnitude.

Comment: @paul I don't mean to be rude, but I don't see a ton of answers on your part that are tagged SQL server. You may not be engaging in this, but I've grown so tired of the common developer bias that it is NEVER better to do any logic in the database. SQL is optimized for set-based operations, which is exactly what is being done here - and especially now that this feature is supported in 2012 I suspect it would be way faster than whatever nested loop structure one would run in code (actually, I would bet even the CTE and the Outer Apply solutions below would outperform most code solutions).

Comment: @ScottEdwards2000 Well, you're free to assume that I lack experience with SQL. Just don't be surprised if I don't concur. I do use T-SQL *a lot*. Also I'm not against doing computations in T-SQL in general. Only in this case, I cannot see how it would make sense. In the app this is a simple rolling average, which is essentially free (no nested loops required). In SQL you have to do a self join which blows up the data set N-fold, and then re-group to get the result. Let SQL Server do the partitioning and sorting, and then just compute the rolling average in the app while fetching the rows.

Comment: @PaulGroke Sorry for being rude.I've worked with too many developers who hate SQL. I see how nested loops aren't required (you basically just aggregate as you bring in the rows) but its not completely free is it?  You will need to maintain a counter variable and check it's value each time you fetch a row. That may be cheaper than the CTE or Outer Apply though. Rows Between window function in 2012 would perform similarly maybe. That's the tough thing with SQL, it's hard to know how much of a row "explosion" is happening, since the optimizer is free to write the plan in a more efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I would probably do it like:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    val1,
    val2,
    ct,
    rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val1 ORDER BY val2)
  FROM table
)
SELECT
  r.val1,
  r.val2,
  avg_ct = AVG(r2.ct)
FROM ranked r
  INNER JOIN ranked r2 ON r2.val1 = r.val1
                      AND r2.rank BETWEEN r.rank - 6 AND r.rank
GROUP BY r.val1, r.val2
```

Definitely not as elegant and concise as the Sybase version, but, as for me, not too bad either.

Comment: The reason I do not like the self join is that the number of rows in question is quite large (probably 12M plus). Won't that blow up?

Comment: @A Question Asker: The join in this query produces an intermediate result set with the row count about 7 times that of the original rowset, in your case it could be like 80-90M or so. I wouldn't call that a *very* large rowset, but it depends of course. If there's a reason to be concerned about the query's performance, you could implement it as an inline TVF, co you could apply a filter on the source dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.myAvgValue from myTable T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT Avg(T3.myValue) myAvgValue FROM myTable T3 WHERE T3.Date BETWEEN T1.Date-7 and T1.Date) T2
```

Hope this helps.